# Issue on hosting dot net core 2.1 application on windows server 2019

Tags: .net-core, windows-server-2019

I hosted dot net core 2.1 web API on windows server 2019.But I get an error "**HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure**"
Please send me any suggestions.

Comment: I already installed sdk3.1 and Dot net core RunTime 3.1

Comment: Are you trying to host it with IIS?

Comment: Yes I host it on IIS @ajawad987

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have installed [.NET Core hosting Bundled](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1) and make sure you set your application pool to No Managed Code. Check this post https://windowswebhostingreview.com/asp-net-core-hosting-3-simple-steps-to-fix-502-5-error-in-asp-net-core/

Answer (score 0):

Hosting on IIS will require one more additional install, the [ASPNET Core Hosting Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

This module installs into IIS to build a bridge between IIS and the underlying Kestral server that ASPNET Core apps run under.

The link above describes the details of hosting on IIS, and also provides a link to download and install the hosting module required for IIS to work with ASPNET Core apps.

Comment: I installed it but Issue is again same.